# Assigning Typescript parameter in .then()

Tags: typescript

I've created some sandbox code to figure out how Typescript works with Promises. When I try to assign a type to the parameter inside the .then() callback, I get an error/warning `Argument of type '(result: Movie[]) => Movie[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => Movie[] | PromiseLike<Movie[]>`.

Everything is working as expected, only I am wondering what is THE way to assign a type to a parameter in the .then() callback? Should I simply use `any`?

```js
class Movie {
  title: string;
  id: number;
  constructor (title: string, id: number) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
  }
}

function getMovies (genre: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve([{ title: 'Passengers', id: 1 }, { title: 'Inception', id: 2 }]);
    }, 300);
  })
}

class MovieService {
  async getMovies(genre: string): Promise<Movie[]> {
    return getMovies(genre).then((result: Movie[]) => result);
  }
}
//Or should I use (result: any) => ... ?

const apiClient = new MovieService()
apiClient.getMovies('sci-fi').then(movies => console.log(movies))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the return value of the freestanding `getMovies`:

```
function getMovies (genre: string): Promise<Movie[]> {
// -------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve([{ title: 'Passengers', id: 1 }, { title: 'Inception', id: 2 }]);
    }, 300);
  })
}
```

...then TypeScript can infer the rest from that.

`resolve` and `reject` are `Function`s.

So:

```
class Movie {
  title: string;
  id: number;
  constructor (title: string, id: number) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
  }
}

function getMovies (genre: string): Promise<Movie[]> {
// Added -------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return new Promise((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
// Changed --------------------^^^^^^^^----------^^^^^^^^
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve([{ title: 'Passengers', id: 1 }, { title: 'Inception', id: 2 }]);
    }, 300);
  })
}

class MovieService {
  async getMovies(genre: string) {
// Removed Promise<Movie[]> ----^
    return getMovies(genre).then(result => result);
// Removed Movie[] --------------------^
  }
}
//Or should I use (result: any) => ... ?

const apiClient = new MovieService()
apiClient.getMovies('sci-fi').then(movies => console.log(movies))
```

So for instance, this fails:

```
const apiClient = new MovieService()
apiClient.getMovies('sci-fi').then(movies => console.log(movies[0].foo))
// Error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Movie'. ---------^^^^
```

But if you want to be explicit throughout:

```
class Movie {
  title: string;
  id: number;
  constructor (title: string, id: number) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
  }
}

function getMovies (genre: string): Promise<Movie[]> {
// -------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return new Promise<Movie[]>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
// -----------------^^^^^^^^^
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve([{ title: 'Passengers', id: 1 }, { title: 'Inception', id: 2 }]);
    }, 300);
  })
}

class MovieService {
  async getMovies(genre: string): Promise<Movie[]> {
// -----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return getMovies(genre).then((result: Movie[]) => result);
// -------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
  }
}
//Or should I use (result: any) => ... ?

const apiClient = new MovieService()
apiClient.getMovies('sci-fi').then((movies: Movie[]) => console.log(movies))
// ---------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

That's a lot of repetition, though. :-)

---

Side Note 1: There's no reason for the `then` handler in `MovieService.prototype.getMovies`, and there's no reason to declare it `async`. It can simply be:

```
getMovies(genre: string) {
  return getMovies(genre);
}
```

Side Note 2: I **really** wouldn't recommend calling the method and the freestanding function it calls exactly the same thing. It just sets up a maintenance hazard (and could easily lead someone to believe it calls itself [it doesn't, but...]).

Comment: What if I made a call to an external API and I receive some objects back of a crazy shape. Is this a good reason to use the 'any' type? Like this for e.g.: https://jsfiddle.net/isachenx/2mbf5avz/

Comment: @OctaviaLo - When and whether to use `any` is entirely up to you. :-)